# How to expand small square input box on hitting search icon in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I have a search-bar with **search icon at the extreme left as shown here in the** [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/39/embedded/result/) **and in the screen shot below**.

[image]

The HTML and CSS codes which I have used in order to make the search icon and the square border is:

**HTML:**

```
<form class="back">
  <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true"> 
</span>
  <input type="text" name="search" class="extand ">
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
.back{
  padding: 0.5%;
  background: #10314c;

}

.searchicon {
   float: left;
   margin-top: -20px;
   position: relative;
   top: 26px;
   left: 8px;
   color: white;
   z-index: 2;
   }

.extand {
    width: 2.4%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #10314c;
    background-position: 10px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.extand-now {
    width: 50%;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

If I hit on the search-icon, **the small square input box (marked by an arrow in the screen shot)** surrounding the search icon should expand similar to [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_anim_search).

Here is my updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p8zrst2p/42/embedded/result/) which is working almost right **but these two things I am not able to figure out how to do it**:

- Square box should come back to the original position after hitting anywhere outside.
- When the white square border expands, the inside background should be white.

Any thoughts on how this can be done?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/p8zrst2p/48/. I fiddled around with your demo to solve your issues in a minimal manner.

Comment: @kleinfreund hey everything looks good in this. There is one thing I think logically make sense to do is - if you look at this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_animated_search.asp). If you click inside search text box then a line keeps blinking which is after that search icon but in your example (in mine too) that blinking line happens before search icon? Is this possible to do the way it is done in w3schools so that blinking line should happen after search icon?

Comment: I updated the demo again. It’s still quite rough but maybe you can learn something from it: https://jsfiddle.net/p8zrst2p/55/.

Comment: @user5447339 if my answer help u , then please accept it

Answer (score 12):

Here is the updated fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/bzksf46s/)

```
.searchicon {
   float: left;
   margin-top: -20px;
   position: relative;
   pointer-events:none; /*Add this to ur css*/
   top: 26px;
   left: 8px;
   color: white;
   z-index: 2;
   }

.extand {
    width: 2.4%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #10314c;
    background-position: 10px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.extand:focus {
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
}
.extand:focus + span{  /*hide icon*/
  display:none;
}
```

no need to add javascript.
On click of **input**, it gets **focused**, which can be used in css to target it and add width to it,
When u click outside, the input gets unfocused and returns back to original size

Answer (score 5):

i think you do't wont to use javascript, you should depend on focus which can be used in css to target it and add width to it, When u click outside, the input gets unfocused and returns back to original size

```css
input{
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/MACjo6S.png);
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input:focus {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

The link that you provide it to smialar [example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_anim_search) does has an icon however the icon image exist in the Css not the HTML, so that once you click on the input or the icon, it animate.

in the case of your code it, it is exist in the html, so that i didn't work,

***solutions:***

1. either you include the icon (image) in the css as a background-image property for the input. (i will leave it up to you how to figure out how you can do it since you have the link and the example ;)
2. you include some JavaScript(JQuery), i believe Jquery is the easiest in this case

***HTML:***

```
    <form class="back">
        <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <input type="text" name="search" class="extand ">
    </form>
```

***CSS:***

```
.back{
   width: 50%;
   background: #10314c;   
}

.searchicon {
   float: left;
   margin-top: -20px;
   position: relative;
   top: 26px;
   left: 8px;
   color: white;
   z-index: 2;
   }

.extand {
   width: 10%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: 2px solid #ccc;
   border-radius: 4px;
   font-size: 16px;
   background: #10314c;
   background-position: 10px 10px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
   transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.extand-now {
   width: 100%;
}
```

***JQuery:*** *include Jquery 3.1.1 slim important*

```
// for the icon
$(".searchicon").click(function() {
  $('.extand').toggleClass('extand-now');
});
// for the input
$(".extand").click(function() {
   $('.extand').toggleClass('extand-now');
});
```

this is demo example : [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/WaelAzar/p8zrst2p/33/)

of course there are many different ways if you want to keep searching

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the code. I tried with the above codes but somehow it didn't work. I am wondering if you can update it in the fiddle.

Comment: i just i edit it, it works
my bad was the class in the input, i just fixed it

Comment: I tried again. Can you update it in the fiddle ? For some reasons, its not working on my pc.

Comment: fiddle has been included in the end of the answer, 
if you find this answer helpful please marked it as answerd

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked your fiddle. If you check my screenshot above, the surrounding marked arrow white square box containing search-icon should expand inside the dark blue search-bar when being search anything. The dark blue search-bar would not change its size in any event. It would remain the same. Hope it helps otherwise I would give you more explanation.

Comment: i just modified it, i think this is what you want and what i understand, i hope this is it.

Comment: you still around? It's working the way I need it but few things are missing. Right now white square box goes back to original position after clicking inside the box but I want it to do same thing even if I click outside as well just like w3schools has example linked in my question? Also When the white square border expands, the inside background should be white? Is this possible to do as well?

Comment: i have checked the w3school, is the that what you want, check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WaelAzar/p8zrst2p/80/)

Answer (score 4):

You could create one parent element for `input` and `icon` elements so that you can position `icon` with position absolute relative to that parent element.

And then you can also create one class, for example `active`, that you can toggle on `focus` and `blur` events on input, but the class will change on that parent element. And then based on that class you can style input and icon.

Note that if you want to change input in `%` and not in `px` that width will depend on parent element. So if you want some other element in the same line as your `form` element then you should use `width` in `px` like this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/p8zrst2p/173/)

```js
$(".form-field input").on('focus blur', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
.back{
  padding: 10px;
  background: #10314c;
}
.form-field {
  position: relative;
}
.form-field i {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 10px;
  top: 50%;
}
.form-field input {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 30px;
  color: white;
  width: 120px;
}
.form-field.active i {
  color: black;
}
.form-field.active input {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="back">
  <div class="form-field">
    <i class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input placeholder="Search..." type="text" name="search" class="extand ">
  </div>
</form>
```

If you want to toggle active class only on `icon` click and remove it also on input `blur` event, you could then use jquery to focus element on `mouseup` event.

```js
$(".form-field i").on('mousedown', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
})

$(".form-field i").on('mouseup', function(e) {
  $(this).next('input').focus()
  if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).next('input').blur()
  }
})

$(".form-field input").on('focus', function(e) {
  if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).blur()
  }
})

$(".form-field input").on('blur', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().removeClass('active')
})
```

```css
.back{
  padding: 10px;
  background: #10314c;
}
.form-field {
  position: relative;
}
.form-field i {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 15px;
  top: 50%;
}
.form-field input {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 35px;
  color: white;
  width: 0;
}
.form-field.active i {
  color: black;
  display: block;
}
i:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form-field.active input {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  width: 300px;
}
.other {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="back">
  <div class="form-field">
    <i class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input type="text" name="search" class="extand ">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify your jQuery

It will remove your expand effect on click on the document anywhere and change background-color of the input field.

```js
$(document).click(function(e){
// this line will check if the user has click on search icon or input
   if( $(e.target).hasClass('searchicon') || $(e.target).hasClass('extand'))   {  
   // this will toggle class and add background css
    $('.extand').toggleClass('extand-now').css('background-color','white');
   
   } else {
   // this will remove class if user click anywhere outside the input field or search icon and set background css
   $('.extand').removeClass('extand-now').css('background-color','#10314c');
   }
});
```

```css
.back{
  padding: 0.5%;
  background: #10314c;
    
}

.searchicon {
   float: left;
   margin-top: -20px;
   position: relative;
   top: 26px;
   left: 8px;
   color: white;
   z-index: 2;
   }
   
.extand {
    width: 2.4%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #10314c;
    background-position: 10px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.extand-now {
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form class="back">
  <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true"> 
</span>
  <input type="text" name="search" class="extand ">
</form>
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p8zrst2p/150/)

Answer (score 3):

I figured you don't want to use JavaScript.
From the code you provided, you only need to add the :focus selector to your extand class. I hope this helps.

```css
.back{
  padding: 2%;
  background: #10314c;
}

.searchicon {
   float: left;
   margin-top: -20px;
   position: relative;
   top: 35px;
   left: 25px;
   color: white;
   z-index: 2;
   }

.extand {
    width: 10%;
    height:45px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #10314c;
    background-position: 10px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 45px; 
    color: white;
}

.extand:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}

.extand:focus {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form class="back">
  <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true"> 
</span>
  <input type="text" name="search" class="extand">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS `:focus` with `transition`. But first you need to set initial value

```css
#ellipsis {
    top: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
}
#ellipsis:focus {
 outline: none;
}
#ellipsis:focus + .dropdown {
 display: block;
}


input[type=text] {
    width: 50%;
    background: #10314c;
    transition: 1s;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 100%;
    background: #10314c;
    transition: 1s;
}


.dropdown {
 background-color: lightblue;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 height: 150px;
 right: 0;
 width: 200px;
 z-index: 10;
}

.searchicon {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 26px;
    left: 8px;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-top-searchbar">
    <form>
        <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <input type="text" name="search">
    <div style="">
     <img tabindex="1" src="https://s9.postimg.org/d6s4xvykv/Ellipsis.png" id="ellipsis">
     <div class="dropdown">
      insert your stuff here
     </div>     
    </div>
        

    </form>
</div>


<div class="body-manage-attendees">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Name
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                Number
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                Table
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Amanda Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Andy Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                14
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                No Bill
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Cameron Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                No Bill
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Dana Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                53
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                5
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Absent
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Eve Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Absent
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Fred Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Fred Doe's Guest1
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Jack Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                14
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Jack Doe's Guest 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                15
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                No Bill
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Jack Doe's Guest 2
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                16
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                5
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Lydia Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Noah Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Meena Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Brenda Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                14
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Cameron Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Brenda Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                14
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Cameron Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Noah Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Bill
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Dana Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                53
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                5
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Unpaid
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Eve Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Items Received
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Fred Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Items Received
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Fred Doe's Guest1
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Items Waiting
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:white;">
                Jack Doe
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                250
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:white;">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="background-color:white;">
                Unpaid
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kiidkupy/nc2djn5p/65/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your code but it didn't work. Can you update in the fiddle ? In that way, I can test it on the fiddle.

Comment: I checked your fiddle. Did you check my problem statement ? I have mentioned the link there. It should work in a way that if I hit on the search icon, it should expand. I can't see any expansion in your fiddle.

Comment: Also, the expansion should take place beneath the search-bar.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<form class="back">
     <input type="text" name="search" class="extand " placeholder="&#x1F50D; Search for something">
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
    *{
        margin:0;
    }

    .back{
      padding: 0.5%;
      background: #10314c;

    }

    .searchicon {
       float: left;
       margin-top: -20px;
       position: relative;
       top: 26px;
       left: 8px;
       color: white;
       z-index: 2;
       }

    .extand {
        width: 2.4%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-size: 16px;
        background: #10314c;
        background-position: 10px 10px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
        transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;

        padding:5px;
    }

/*use :focus to expand the input field (search bar) on focus*/

    .extand:focus{
        background-color:#fff;
        color:black;
        width:40%;
    }
```

Here's a jsFidde: https://jsfiddle.net/r5kLh7p6/3/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding the :hover and :focus selector to your extand class.
I hope this helps

```css
.back{
  padding: 2%;
  background: #10314c;
}

.searchicon {
   float: left;
   margin-top: -20px;
   position: relative;
   top: 30px;
   left: 20px;
   color: white;
   z-index: 2;
   }

.extand {
    width: 12%;
    height:40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #10314c;
    background-position: 10px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
 
}

.extand:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.extand:focus {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.extand:focus + .searchicon {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form class="back">
  <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true"> 
</span>
  <input type="text" name="search" class="extand">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior that you're looking for is to modify its width when you focus (click your mouse inside of it):

```
input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 100%;
}
```

But before changing its width you'll need to give it a lower value, for example:

```
input[type=text] {
    width: 20%;
    background: #10314c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your code but it didn't work. Can you update in the fiddle  ?

Comment: I checked your fiddle. Did you check my problem statement ? I have mentioned the link there. It should work in a way that if I hit on the search icon, it should expand. I can't see any expansion in your fiddle.

Comment: I am explaining it one more time. If you check my screenshot above, the surrounding marked arrow white square box containing search-icon should expand inside the dark blue search-bar when being search anything. The dark blue search-bar would not change its size in any event. It would remain the same. Hope it helps otherwise I would give you more explanation

Answer (score 1):

This can be done like this

```css
.back {
  padding: 0.5%;
  background: #10314c;
}

.searchicon {
  float: left;
  margin-top: -20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 24px;
  left: 8px;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
}

.extend {
  width: 24%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #10314c;
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.extend:focus {
  width: 50%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<form class="back">
  <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true"> 
</span>
  <input type="text" name="search" class="extend ">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified your "updated" fiddle to get to this result:

https://jsfiddle.net/p8zrst2p/98/

I modified just a little the CSS (color and width of the icon),
then used a CSS `:focus` selector, like this:

```
.extand:focus {
    width: 50%;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Using `:focus` selector is, in my opinion, the easier and proper way to achieve what you want.

Then… I wanted to remove the JS at first, but finally I used it like this:
The click on the icon sets the focus on the input, so that the CSS above is applied. That's all.

```
// Focus input when icon clicked
$(".searchicon").click(function() {
  $('.extand').focus();
});
```

Is that the way you wanted it to be?
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Solution for the search icon expand,
JSfiddle Demo - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/215/)

CSS (only added this part) -

```
.search {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
    width: 85%;
}

.search.toggle-off {
    width: 22px;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.search .searchicon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 22px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 3px;
}

.search input[type=text] {
  width: calc(100% - 22px);
  background: #10314c;
}
```

HTML (only edit this part) -

```
<div class="search toggle-off">
  <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <input type="text" name="search">
</div>
```

JS -

```
var searchicon = document.querySelector(".searchicon"),
search = document.querySelector(".search");

searchicon.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(search.classList.contains("toggle-off")){
        search.classList.remove("toggle-off");
    }
    else{
        search.classList.add("toggle-off");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

```css
.back{
  padding: 0.5%;
  background: #10314c;
    
}

.searchicon {
   float: left;
   margin-top: -20px;
   position: relative;
   top: 26px;
   left: 8px;
   color: white;
   z-index: 2;
   /* Allows focusing the input element *through* the search icon */
   pointer-events: none;
}
   
.extand {
    width: 4%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding-left:30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #10314c;
    background-position: 10px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.extand:focus {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.extand:focus + .searchicon {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<form class="back">
  <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true"> 
</span>
  <input type="text" name="search" class="extand ">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this works for you:

> If you don't mind I have change the order of your element

I have only used **CSS** to achieve this result.

```css
.back {
  padding: 0.5%;
  background: #10314c;
}

.searchicon {
  float: left;
  margin-top: -22px;
  position: relative;
  top: 26px;
  left: 8px;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 18px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.extand {
  width: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #10314c;
  color:#10314c;/* I have used same color as the background so after the search the text will not visible to the user */
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;/* Set curson pointer so the user think it's a button of search */
}

.extand:focus,
.extand:active {
  width: 50%;
  cursor: text;/* To change the curson to text */
  background: #fff;
  outline: none;
}

.extand:focus+.searchicon,
.extand:active+.searchicon {
  display: none;/* this will hide the search icon on click of the input */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="back">
  <input type="text" name="search" class="extand ">
  <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true"> 
  </span>
</form>
```

I think above code will cover all your needs. If there is anything else please do post a comment, I will try my best to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the focus and parent child property

```
.back:focus ~ .extand{
    width:50%;  /*increase width as per your choice.
}
```

But reverse is not going to work.As extand class is nested inside back.

Answer (score 0):

> - Square box should come back to the original position after hitting anywhere outside.

You might update your jQuery code to this:

```js
// for the icon
$(".searchicon").click(function() {
  $('.extand').focus();
});
// for the input
$(".extand").focus(function() {
   $('.extand').addClass('extand-now');
}).blur(function() {
   $('.extand').removeClass('extand-now');
});
```